# Cassandra statistics about coordinator nodes

Tags: cassandra

After a constant flow of read/write operations to a Cassandra cluster, I would like to know, for each node of the cluster, for how many read/write requests the node has been used as coordinator.

I would like to know if the read/write requests are distributed uniformly/randomly in the entire cluster or some particular nodes get chosen as coordinators more often than the others.

I have not found this kind of statistic on nodetool. Is there a way to obtain this data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are JMX MBeans that track coordinator metrics.  They are `org.apache.cassandra.metrics.ClientRequest.Read` and `...ClientRequest.Write`.  There's a `Count` attribute on each of them that will give you the number of reads and writes that the node has coordinated.

I don't believe the count is currently exposed through any tools, although latencies are (through `nodetool proxyhistograms`).